# Textbox value set to null when changing tabs

Tags: model-view-controller, tabs, textbox, null

I am using the javascript tabular feature. I have hidden textboxes in one tab that I am reading values from. When reading values from the same tab the value works perfectly.

But when change the tab the value of textbox resets to null.

How can I get this value so it wont be lost.

Thanks

Comment: which Tabular feature ? give link of demo ?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: if the name/id of the hideen values are not dynamic put it out of tabbs !